# Update React state when Database Updates Socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, socket.io

I have a react app connected to my Node Server and Mongo db

Server.js

```
//Mongodb Watching for Changes

Orders.watch().on('change', dataBaseUpdate => {
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
        socket.emit("update", dataBaseUpdate);
    });
    console.log(dataBaseUpdate);
});
```

Every time  there is an update I emit the Object updated to the React Frontend

Client.js

```
//Logs the object every time I refresh the page
socket.on("update", (updatedObject) => {
  console.log(updatedObject)
})
```

------   It logs on the front end perfectly Perfectly  But....

how do I refresh a Component automatically every time there is a change in the database

For example:
I have a component with a list of orders from the database
then.. Database changes in the server
and..  React Automatically refreshes the list

Thanks

Comment: The same way you always update React components: by changing their state or props.  If you pass that data to your component's state or props, it'll update.  Sagas or thunks are good for this.

Comment: Well I use the  

   const [update, setUpdate] = useState({});

then I start updating the state using

  useEffect(() => {

    socket.on("update", (updatedObject) => {
      setUpdate(updatedObject)
    })
  }, [])

console.log(update) // Logs the data

but when I update the Database the old value stays and dont update

Comment: You should add this code to your question, rather in a comment.  Sounds like there are more relevant pieces.

Comment: Yes sorry about that let me add the code